# Spring Data Cassandra query returns InvalidQueryException, "unconfigured table"

Tags: spring-boot, cassandra, datastax-java-driver, spring-data-cassandra

```
@Table("person_details")
class Person{

 @PrimaryKeyColumn(value = "person_id", type = PrimaryKeyType.PARTITIONED)
private String personId;

  @Column(value = "age")  
  private Integer age;

  public void setAge(Integer age){
   this.age = age;
  }
  public Integer getAge(){
   return age;
  }
}
```

> ```
>  public interface PresonRepo extends CassandraRepository<Person,
>  String>{
>      @AllowFiltering 
>      findAllByAgeGreaterThan(int age) }
> ```

Error:

```
InvalidQueryException: unconfigured table person_details
```

> ```
> Log:
>
>     Preparing statement [SELECT * FROM "person_details" WHERE age>?
> ```

Working with @Query annotation

```
@Query("select * from person_details where age >?0 ALLOW FILTERING")
findByAgeGreaterThan (int age); //success
}
```

No Idea why It is behaving like this.

versions:

- cassandra driver - 4.15.0
- spring boot 2.7.7
- spring data cassandra 3.4.6

Comment: You may want to add more code. Here the person Class is empty and shoud contain at very least `age`. Also your request is not correct: with Cassandra you need a partition key and perform equality before an inequality. Does the table exists ? What "describe keyspace" give you as output with cqlsh ?

Comment: My entity class has everything. Just  I have formatted my details

Answer (score 0):

I suspect the CQL table does not get created because your code is incomplete.

Typically, you need to specify the primary key plus the columns of the table. However, you haven't defined any of these in your `Person` class.

If you're interested, we have a library of examples that include the full source code at [datastax.com/examples](https://www.datastax.com/examples), particularly the [Spring Data Astra DB REST API](https://www.datastax.com/examples/spring-data-starter) example which you could use as a guide for building your application. Cheers!

Comment: Hi Erick
Table is existing and I can query from CQLsh.
@Query annotation with native query is working and I am getting result.
@Query("select * from person_details where age >?0 ALLOW FILTERING")

The following is not working and throwing the error mentioned.

findAllByAgeGreaterThan(int age)

I have tried "@AllowFiltering" annotation as well not working

Comment: Only difference I can see in the log

Preparing statement [SELECT * FROM "person_details" WHERE age>?
here table name is quoted.

Answer (score 0):

Wait a second:

```
SELECT * FROM "person_details" WHERE age > ? ALLOW FILTERING;
```

Does that actually work?  If it does, that means that the quotes are a part of the table name.  You can verify this by running `desc tables` in cqlsh.

If so, then you'll need to add the `forceQuote` option to your table annotation:

```
@Table(value = "person_details", forceQuote = true)
```

Comment: Hi Aaron
Thanks for the response.
That query will not work. It will work without double quote.